# How To Grab All Type Of Attachments, But Images?

Tags: attachments

I need to get all file attachments which is not an image,
'post_mime_type' only accepts "any" or specific mime types,

How to grab all type of attachments, but images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress has a function, [`get_allowed_mime_types`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types), which will return all allowed types. We can filter this list and exclude any types containing `image`, then query for all remaining types by passing them as a comma separated list to `post_mime_type`. This may not be the most efficient way to do it, you may be better off filtering [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where), but it'll work.

```
$filtered_mime_types = array();

foreach( get_allowed_mime_types() as $key => $type ):
    if( false === strpos( $type, 'image' ) )
        $filtered_mime_types[] = $type;
endforeach;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_mime_type' => implode( ',', $filtered_mime_types )
);

$results = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: It seems get_allowed_mime_types will be solve my problem, but that was very boring problem on wp

Comment: `post_mime_type` also takes array as an value, no need to `implode()`